# pgAdmin 4 Database Restore

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, restore, pgadmin

This is my first question. Please bear with me if I am not stating the question clearly.

When I try to restore a database using "dvdrental.tar" file, the following is the screenshot of the restore option.
[Restore Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5qk0.gif)

Then the failed exit code: 3221225595 appears.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnaKT.png)

I was wondering whether anyone would help me with this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: potentially a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401460/postgres-psql-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old version of pgadmin4 which has a bug where it does not accurately convey the error message back to you.  The big blank box between the Start Time and the Failed should contain a message.